Laravel 10: File Upload Validation Errors in PHP 8.1 - How to Resolve?
so i am getting this validation error when trying to upload an image of size greater than 1.5MB. validation code. However when submitting images of total size greater than any amount let's say 10MB it's fine, only when individual image size is greater than 1.5MB I get an error
[2024-06-11 19:11:44] local.ERROR: Validation Error {"errors":{"cert_attach.0":["The cert_attach.0 failed to upload."]}}

I have already edited these in my php.ini:
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
memory_limit = 256M
max_execution_time = 300
max_input_time = 300

and nginx.conf:
client_max_body_size 20M;

I don't know what else could be the issue

How do you send your request? Using an HTML form, JavaScirpt, Postman? Please confirm and add the request to the question.
